# Hyper-V with multiple physical networks

Tags: networking, windows-8, hyper-v

I have Hyper-V on my laptop with a wireless and Ethernet card, sometimes I connect using wireless card, and sometimes using the Ethernet cable.

I am trying to configure Hyper-v to work always with internet provided to virtual machine.

I have tried to create 2 virtual switches, one external to the Wireless network card, and the other one external to the Ethernet card.

What happens is that the wireless network creates a bridge object in the network and sharing center\Network connections of windows 8, while the Ethernet does not.

Unfortunately, they do not work together as external, i have to set the connected one to external and the other one as external, I also have to go to the properties of the bridge and virtual Ethernet properties to uncheck and check some components like:

- Client for Microsoft Networks
- Deterministic Network Enhancer
- VMWare Bridge Protocol
- QoS Packet Scheduler
- File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks

In order to make things work.

Sometimes I keep the wireless network switch external, and go to another location (another wireless network), and it disconnects, i have to reconfigure the switches.

Is there a way to do the configuration once and remain working wherever I connect, whether its Wireless or Ethernet and on any network with DHCP?

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Comment: There were some views, but no answers, is more information required ?